# Changing div width using JQuery UI slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, width

I am trying to dynamically change the width of a div using a slider.
I get the element ID by using a click function.
I then pass this ID into a variable.
I use this variable to determine which element ID i am adjusting
Everything works fine except for the last line. Nothing happens and no errors.

Just to clarify a little more, in the JS fiddle when you drag it will update the selected element. How do i bring that element into the slider to adjust its width?
I have tried getting the id attribute of the element and storing it in a global variable and then calling that variable in the slider and updating its CSS.
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8enwc69j)

UPDATE:
Solved! I should have added a class onto the selected element instead of trying to store it in a variable.
    var divHolder // holds element from click function

```
$('#changeWidth').slider({
    value: 0,
    slide: function(event, slider) {

    var theSliderValue = slider.value + "%";
    alert(divHolder); // Returns the div id i wanted
    $("#divHolder").css("width", theSliderValue);
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you add some info from your markup, or better yet, [put it in a JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: added JS fiddle of what ive got so far, basically when you drag a div, it updates the holder variable, and i want the slider to adjust its width 
https://jsfiddle.net/8enwc69j/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this basically what you're trying to do?

https://jsfiddle.net/02o6a583/3/

```
$('.slider').slider({
    values: [0, 100],
    slide: function(event, ui){
        $('.expand-me').css('width', ui.value + '%');
    } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes that is exactly what i want to have happen. Except i want to be able to select one of multiple divs and use the slider to change the width of the selected div. I think the problem is with the variable that is holding the selected div. Am i not selecting it right?

Comment: I hit enter to quickly on that last comment. Meant to say that you need to add in a click handler to check the divs for state and whether or not they have been clicked. Here is an updated fiddle with that added in. https://jsfiddle.net/02o6a583/5/